# Bootstrap v2.1.1 - no Google Maps

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Google maps does not display on my page. It seems to be a problem associated with Twitter Bootstrap. After doing some research, it seems that this should solve the problem:

```
#map_canvas label { width: auto; display:inline; }
#map_canvas img { max-width: none; max-height: none; }
```

It does nothing for me. I still don't see the map. I'm using Bootstrap v2.1.1. Not sure if the solution I found was for that version of Bootstrap. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I use Bootstrap 2.1.1 and Google maps. Here is what works for me using...

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>

<style>
#map_canvas
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
</style>
```

The initialization script...

```
function InitializeMap() {
   var myOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: myLatlng,
      panControl: false,
      panControlOptions: {
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
      },
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
         style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
      },
      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: {
         style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
      },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }
   myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatlng, map: myMap, title: "yyyZ, Ltd." });
   var contentString = "1122 N Clark Street<br />Chicago, IL 60610";
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString });
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      if (lastOpenInfoWin) lastOpenInfoWin.close();
      lastOpenInfoWin = infowindow;
      infowindow.open(myMap, marker);
      myMap.setCenter(myLatlng);
   });

   var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
   trafficLayer.setMap(myMap);
}
```

You can see the result at http://reactivewebdesign.net/Chicago/Traffic

From the left menu, yopu can also select "Where am I" which uses google maps and geo location.